# Datepicker title

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker and I need to put a text in the title. I found this code but the text is repeated every time the page is reloaded:

```
$( "input" ).datepicker()
.on( "focus", function() {
$('.ui-datepicker').prepend('<div class="datepicker_tit1">Text<div/>');
});
```

Anyone know another way?

Comment: How many datepickers are there in the page

Comment: There are two datepickers

Answer (score 1):

Check if the title exists already before adding on focus

```
$( "#input" ).datepicker().on( "focus", function() {    
  if(!$('.ui-datepicker').find('#input_header').length){
    $('.ui-datepicker').prepend('<div id="input_header" class="datepicker_tit1">Select a date<div/>');  
  }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work,

```
var myBool = false;
$( "input" ).datepicker().on( "focus", function() {
    if(myBool == false)
    {
        $('.ui-datepicker').prepend('<div class="datepicker_tit1">Text<div/>');
    }
    myBool = true;
});
```

This way the prepend only takes place the first time the focus event is called.

Comment: Thanks but the text disappears when I change the month :/

Comment: If you can post all the code you are referring to it would probably help.